# How does the java compiler exit void methods?

Tags: java

When the compiler reaches the end of a void method does it just call `return;` ? Can anyone tell me where I can find documentation on such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you look at the byte code `javap -c class`, you will see the `RETURN` instruction in void methods.

You can find out more about bytecode by reading the [JVM specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The RETURN opcode (B1) is automatically inserted at the end of a void method if missing, you can manually put this in if you wish too though